# Xcode - deleted openFrameworks libraries, now can't compile and having trouble re-adding

Tags: iphone, xcode, objective-c++, openframeworks

I was 'cleaning up' a project and deleted some of the references to `libs` used with `openFrameworks`. Certain things weren't being used, or so I mistakenly thought... Panic in my project!

All sorts of errors, of course. But, XCode won't let me undo that sort of action. I've re-added the `libs` but the errors persist. Can someone explain to me what basic conceptual thing I'm missing?

Errors go like this [edited]:

```
/Developer/openFrameworks-iPhone/libs/openFrameworks/app/ofAppGlutWindow.cpp:61: error: 'glutInit' was not declared in this scope
/Developer/openFrameworks-iPhone/libs/openFrameworks/app/ofAppGlutWindow.cpp:62: error: 'GLUT_RGB' was not declared in this scope
/Developer/openFrameworks-iPhone/libs/openFrameworks/app/ofAppGlutWindow.cpp:62: error: 'GLUT_DOUBLE' was not declared in this scope
```

**[UPDATE]**. Two things to check: (1) Having a valid build of the oF library itself. Open library project, make sure it builds.

(2) Is the oF library (and all the other, dependent libraries such as Poco) being added in the **Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries** section? Sometimes when you delete and then re-add a library, it doesn't get included on this list. Re-drag the library files here. That's what ultimately solved this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: Had to manually add the appropriate libraries to be included under "Build Phases". Built the clean download of openFrameworks that way; afterward I could add that to projects referencing the library and build them!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clean build? I got this error once when adding static libraries.

Comment: I have never used this lib before but is there a simulator and device version of this lib? Or have you tried the simulator and device debug and none of them work?

Comment: Both don't work. Also, a clean re-download of openFrameworks doesn't build anymore...

Comment: For anyone coming to this later: I ended up having trouble with `emptyExample` for ages, but all other examples would build fine. A workaround, yes, but an easy one.